# Adding number from text file to axis label

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a bunch of standalone tikz images that I need to add a number to the axis label. The number that I add to each label is in a text file that may change depending on which dataset I use. Is there a way to read the text file containing this number and insert it in the y-axis label? Where XXX.XX is the value that I read from the text file.

Example text file: [`Wall_Tempartures.txt`](http://pastebin.com/yPRyR2bH)

[image]

```
\documentclass[class=minimal,border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage[condensed,light]{roboto}    % Add font for figures
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                % Specify font encoding
\usepackage{mathptmx}

%Define colors for plotting
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0.125,0.500,0.169}
\definecolor{darkred}  {rgb}{0.900,0.100,0.100}
\tikzset{>=latex}   % Change default arrow tip style

\newcommand{\labelsize}{\fontsize{9pt}{9pt}\selectfont}
\newcommand{\footnotesize}{\fontsize{7pt}{7pt}\selectfont}
\newcommand{\footfootnotesize}{\fontsize{5pt}{5pt}\selectfont}
\newcommand{\linewidths}{0.75pt}
\newcommand{\errormarksize}{3pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotsset{every axis legend/.append style={at={(0.5,0.03)},anchor=south,nodes=right},
    legend style={font={\footnotesize}}}

    \begin{axis}[name=topplot,clip mode=individual,
        axis background/.style={fill=white},
        width=2.5in,height=2.5in,
        xmin=0,xmax=2000,
        ymin=-0.01,ymax=0.03,
        tick scale binop=\times,
        minor tick num=4,
        legend columns=2,
        xlabel={$z$-Position, [mm]},
        ytick pos=both,
        ylabel={\labelsize $\theta = \frac{T-T_\textrm{\footfootnotesize amb}}{T_\textrm{\footfootnotesize amb}}$, $\left[ \frac{\Delta \textrm{\footnotesize K}}{\textrm{\footnotesize K}} \right]$, $T_\textrm{\footfootnotesize amb}$= XXX.XX K},
        scaled y ticks=false,
        y tick label style={
            /pgf/number format/.cd,
            fixed,
            fixed zerofill,
            precision=2,
            /tikz/.cd}]

        \addplot+[blue,only marks,mark=o,line width=\linewidths,mark size=1.5,
                error bars/.cd,
                    y dir=both,
                    y explicit,
                    error bar style={line width=\linewidths},
                    error mark options={rotate=90,mark size=\errormarksize,
                    line width=\linewidths}]
            table[x index=0,y index=1,y error index=13] {Wall_Temperatures.txt};
            \addlegendentry{Top Wall}
        \addplot+[red,only marks,mark=square,line width=\linewidths,mark size=1.5,
                error bars/.cd,
                    y dir=both,
                    y explicit,
                    error bar style={line width=\linewidths},
                    error mark options={rotate=90,mark size=\errormarksize,
                    line width=\linewidths}]
            table[x index=0,y index=4,y error index=16] {Wall_Temperatures.txt};
            \addlegendentry{Left Wall}
        \addplot+[darkgreen,only marks,mark=triangle,line width=\linewidths,mark size=1.5,
                error bars/.cd,
                    y dir=both,
                    y explicit,
                    error bar style={line width=\linewidths},
                    error mark options={rotate=90,mark size=\errormarksize,
                    line width=\linewidths}]
            table[x index=0,y index=7,y error index=19] {Wall_Temperatures.txt};
            \addlegendentry{Plate}
        \addplot+[violet,only marks,mark=x,line width=\linewidths,mark size=2.0,
                error bars/.cd,
                    y dir=both,
                    y explicit,
                    error bar style={line width=\linewidths},
                    error mark options={rotate=90,mark size=\errormarksize,
                    line width=\linewidths}]
            table[x index=0,y index=10,y error index=22] {Wall_Temperatures.txt};
            \addlegendentry{Right Wall} 

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide the community with at least a starting document that reflects your current setup. That way we don't have to recreate that starting point *from scratch*.

Comment: Added my code and a link to the files.

Comment: What is in the text file containing the ambient temperature? If it's only a number, then you can use `\input`, but if it needs parsing then we need to know what to parse.

Comment: It is just a number but the formatting isn't necessarily correct. Is there a way to modify how `\input` displays the number?

Comment: @KyleJones See if my answer helped. Tip about comments: usually, people aren't notified, adding `@username` ensures that they are. (You can only ping those who previously commented, or edited the post though.) Tab completion of user names is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a suggestion. First read the content of the temperaturefile into a macro with the help of the `catchfile` package:

```
\usepackage{catchfile}
\CatchFileDef{\AT}{ambtemp.txt}{}
```

Add `\usepackage{siunitx}` and use this to parse and print the number with unit, e.g. `\SI[round-mode=places,round-precision=2]{\AT}{\kelvin}`. See the manual of `siunitx` for all the possible options.

[image]

```
\documentclass[class=minimal,border=0pt]{standalone}
% for number parsing and units
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

% I don't have this one
%\usepackage[condensed,light]{roboto}    % Add font for figures
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                % Specify font encoding
\usepackage{mathptmx}

% just for example, writes a number to a file
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{ambtemp.txt}
273.947572094827
\end{filecontents*}
% read in ambient temperature and save in macro \AT
\usepackage{catchfile}
\CatchFileDef{\AT}{ambtemp.txt}{}

%Define colors for plotting
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0.125,0.500,0.169}
\definecolor{darkred}  {rgb}{0.900,0.100,0.100}
\tikzset{>=latex}   % Change default arrow tip style

\newcommand{\labelsize}{\fontsize{9pt}{9pt}\selectfont}
\newcommand{\footnotesize}{\fontsize{7pt}{7pt}\selectfont}
\newcommand{\footfootnotesize}{\fontsize{5pt}{5pt}\selectfont}
\newcommand{\linewidths}{0.75pt}
\newcommand{\errormarksize}{3pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotsset{every axis legend/.append style={at={(0.5,0.03)},anchor=south,nodes=right},
    legend style={font={\footnotesize}}}

    \begin{axis}[name=topplot,clip mode=individual,
        axis background/.style={fill=white},
        width=2.5in,height=2.5in,
        xmin=0,xmax=2000,
        ymin=-0.01,ymax=0.03,
        tick scale binop=\times,
        minor tick num=4,
        legend columns=2,
        xlabel={$z$-Position, [mm]},
        ytick pos=both,
        ylabel={\labelsize $\theta = \frac{T-T_\textrm{\footfootnotesize amb}}{T_\textrm{\footfootnotesize amb}}$, $\left[ \frac{\Delta \textrm{\footnotesize K}}{\textrm{\footnotesize K}} \right]$, $T_\textrm{\footfootnotesize amb}= \SI[round-mode=places,round-precision=2]{\AT}{\kelvin}$},
        scaled y ticks=false,
        y tick label style={
            /pgf/number format/.cd,
            fixed,
            fixed zerofill,
            precision=2,
            /tikz/.cd}]

        \addplot+[blue,only marks,mark=o,line width=\linewidths,mark size=1.5,
                error bars/.cd,
                    y dir=both,
                    y explicit,
                    error bar style={line width=\linewidths},
                    error mark options={rotate=90,mark size=\errormarksize,
                    line width=\linewidths}]
            table[x index=0,y index=1,y error index=13] {Wall_Temperatures.txt};
            \addlegendentry{Top Wall}
        \addplot+[red,only marks,mark=square,line width=\linewidths,mark size=1.5,
                error bars/.cd,
                    y dir=both,
                    y explicit,
                    error bar style={line width=\linewidths},
                    error mark options={rotate=90,mark size=\errormarksize,
                    line width=\linewidths}]
            table[x index=0,y index=4,y error index=16] {Wall_Temperatures.txt};
            \addlegendentry{Left Wall}
        \addplot+[darkgreen,only marks,mark=triangle,line width=\linewidths,mark size=1.5,
                error bars/.cd,
                    y dir=both,
                    y explicit,
                    error bar style={line width=\linewidths},
                    error mark options={rotate=90,mark size=\errormarksize,
                    line width=\linewidths}]
            table[x index=0,y index=7,y error index=19] {Wall_Temperatures.txt};
            \addlegendentry{Plate}
        \addplot+[violet,only marks,mark=x,line width=\linewidths,mark size=2.0,
                error bars/.cd,
                    y dir=both,
                    y explicit,
                    error bar style={line width=\linewidths},
                    error mark options={rotate=90,mark size=\errormarksize,
                    line width=\linewidths}]
            table[x index=0,y index=10,y error index=22] {Wall_Temperatures.txt};
            \addlegendentry{Right Wall} 

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```